# Parsing KML to Google Maps only shows one of hundreds of pins

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, google-earth

**My Expectations**

I'm working my way through Violent Python and am currently on a module where I'm grabbing ip-addresses from a .pcap-file, parsing the ip-addresses to longitudes and latitudes and finally parsing those longs and langs into a .kml file.

The idea is that my .kml file should be uploadable to Google Earth and Google Maps to show pins for the source and destination of each captured package.

---

**What is actually happening:**

- On Google Earth the parsing fails with no error message other than

> Parsing Aborted

- On Google Maps I only see the a single pin in Amsterdam. It would seem to be the first `<placemark>` with IP: **212.204.214.114.**

---

**Code and other important stuffz:**

You can find the [**whole .kml-file here**](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1N9tykX90KuKFmKRoIToowuVZ5RrjzMTMS7hv6rt18RQ/edit?usp=sharing).

The headers are correct (if the book and other SO threads are to believed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
```

And all of the placemarks have this simple structure:

```
<Placemark>
    <name>212.204.214.114</name>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>4.834300, 52.404800</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
```

My code follows the same structure as the module in Violent Python, with some small changes to better follow more modern best practices:

```
import dpkt, socket, pygeoip, argparse, os

gi = pygeoip.GeoIP('/opt/GeoIP/Geo.dat')

def ret_klm(ip):
    rec = gi.record_by_name(ip)

    try:
        long = rec['longitude']
        lat  = rec['latitude']
        kml = (
            '<Placemark>\n'
            '<name>%s</name>\n'
            '<Point>\n'
            '<coordinates>%6f, %6f</coordinates>\n'
            '</Point>\n'
            '</Placemark>\n'
            )%(ip, long, lat)
        return kml
    except:
        return ''


def plotIPs(pcap):
    kml_points = ''
    for (ts, buf) in pcap:
        try:
            eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
            ip  = eth.data
            src = socket.inet_ntoa(ip.src)
            src_kml = ret_klm(src)
            dst = socket.inet_ntoa(ip.dst)
            dst_kml = ret_klm(dst)
            kml_points = kml_points + src_kml + dst_kml
        except:
            pass

    return kml_points

def main():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=u'GeoLocator to parse IP addresses to their '
                    u'long, lat in KML for Google Maps.'
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        u'-p',
        help=u'Pcap file for parsing',
        required=True,
        dest=u'pcap_file'
    )
    arguments = parser.parse_args()

    if not os.path.isfile(arguments.pcap_file):
        parser.print_usage()
        raise SystemExit

    with open(arguments.pcap_file) as file:
        pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(file)
        kmlheader = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'+\
            '\n<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">\n'
        kmlfooter = '</kml>\n'
        kmldoc = kmlheader + plotIPs(pcap) + kmlfooter
        print(kmldoc)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a <Document> element to your KML that will wrap all of your <Placemark> elements.  Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <Placemark>
        <name>212.204.214.114</name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>4.834300, 52.404800</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>212.204.214.114</name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>4.834300, 52.404800</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <!-- the rest of your placemarks -->
</Document>
</kml>
```